# Change variable set using ng-init in parent block

Tags: angularjs

I need to use a variable as the condition in the ng-if directive, which is set in parent div using ng-init.

```
<div ng-repeat="item in list" ng-init="flag = false">
  <div>
    <div ng-if="item == a" ng-init="flag = true">
      <!-- Some html code -->
    </div>
    <div ng-if="item == b" ng-init="flag = true">
      <!-- Some html code -->
    </div>
  </div>
  <div ng-if="flag == false">
    <!-- Some html code -->
  </div>
</div>
```

Can anyone tell me how to get this done?

**Edit**

I wanted to check whether each item in a list (`list_a`) is present in another list (`list_b`).

And for each item in `list_a`, display one div if present or display another div if not present in `list_b`.

Comment: The `ng-init` directive can be abused to add unnecessary amounts of logic into your templates. There are only a few appropriate uses of `ngInit`. For more information, see [AngularJS `ng-init` Directive API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit). New AngularJS developers often do not realize that `ng-repeat`, `ng-switch`, `ng-view`, `ng-include` and `ng-if` all create new child scopes. See [What are the nuances of scope inheritance in AngularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14049480/what-are-the-nuances-of-scope-prototypal-prototypical-inheritance-in-angularjs)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To check whether the `item`, in `list_a`, is present in the `list_b` and display a block if present, I used

`<div ng-if="list_b.indexOf(item)+1">`

And to display another div if `item` is not present in the second list,

`<div ng-if="!(list_b.indexOf(item)+1)">`

Answer (score 1):

forget about ng-init, create simple directive and include that wherever you need

```
<div ng-repeat="item in list">
    <div>
        <div ng-if="item == a">
            <!-- Some html code for a -->
        </div>
        <div ng-if="item == b">
            <!-- Some html code for b-->
        </div>
    </div>
    <div ng-if="item != a && item != b">
        <!-- Some html code -->
        <!--or some directive-->
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I am using another list to store the list of items(a,b,..). In that case, what is the best way?

Comment: try to figure out yourself. try to understand what you want. angular gives you the way to write conditional tags like ng-if ng-show, based on them you could show/hide big html blocks